# Django models - how to cancel on_delete=models.CASCADE

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, cascading-deletes

Trying to migrate a field from cascade to "non-cascade" seems to be ignored (Django 1.10).

Previous model:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    ...
    analysis_retention = models.ForeignKey('analysis_retention.AnalysisRetention',
                                           null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

New Model:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    ...
    analysis_retention = models.ForeignKey('analysis_retention.AnalysisRetention',
                                           null=True, default=None)
```

"manage.py makemigrations" doesn't detect the changes.
Trying an explicit None doesn't help.

What would be the way to remove cascading?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`CASCADE` is default value for `on_delete` argument, see [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.4/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L757). So deleting `on_delete=models.CASCADE` will not have effect. You need to specify `on_delete` value in code:

```
analysis_retention = models.ForeignKey('analysis_retention.AnalysisRetention',
                                       null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you.